# Does SQL Server compute results that are later discarded?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are currently running SQL Server 2016 and we noticed something that got us thinking.

We were running a query on a table that *sometimes* caused a division by zero.

The setup is something like this

```
SELECT 
    PT.ID, SUM(FT.Value1 / FT.Value2)
FROM 
    PrimaryTable PT
JOIN 
    ForeignTable FT ON PT.ID = FT.ForeignID
WHERE 
    PT.Date >= @DateStart
    AND PT.Date < @DateEnd
```

Now the fix is pretty obvious using `NULLIF` on the FT.Value2 to avoid division by zero.

However, we couldn't find any row that would actually cause the server to run into this issue at all if restricted to the filtered dates. Curiously, it also did not occur reliably. We could track that down, that it was depending on how many rows actually existed in both tables. If it did occur - it was reproducible. However if other operations added, deleted or modified rows, it might be the case that the division by zero does not occur.

The server is running as a Hyper-V machine with 8 virtual cores and enough RAM to put both tables in more than 10 times over. So I thought maybe parallel computation could be the cause of the issue.

Is SQL Server actually computing column results ahead of filtering by the where statement? Or why would it run into a division by zero if none of the affected rows actually would cause such a division.

Comment: Oh yes, and it's probably [worse than you ever imagined](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). The long and short of it is that any expression you write should basically be valid in every context you can think of, since `WHERE` won't necessarily bail you out, and sometimes not even `CASE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, the query engine can choose different plans which can result in scalars being computed before filtering, or the other way around. Especially since it can peek the passed in parameters to decide on what it believes is the best plan for those specific params.

If you were able to pull the 2 different query plans for a successful run and a failed run you should be able to see that.

If may be possible to use an `optimize for unknown`, or `optimize for (Values)` clause to help prevent this changing of behaviour.

As Jeroen points out, this is not guaranteed to work, you could fix the plan with a `USE PLAN` hint, but none of these things are as desirable as fixing the query itself to handle the issue.

Comment: I agree with everything except the last paragraph. Using `OPTIMIZE FOR` (or any other hint) may avoid the error if you're lucky, but adds no reliability. Insidiously, queries can fail depending on what data passes through a parallel operator with no plan change, so unless you actually spelled out a safe execution plan with a plan guide, a query hint on its own would not be enough to guarantee anything.

Comment: I agreed in that I think the hint is far less desirable than fixing the query itself, but if there is a known set of good inputs that produce a good plan it can be used as a stop gap - or as you say, use the USE PLAN hint. (I'd still prefer to fix the query over that though) - I will include within the answer so the point is not missed.

Comment: The problem is that even if `OPTIMIZE FOR` "works", and even if you then fix it with `USE PLAN`, you may find that the plan is actually still not safe under all circumstances, but you won't find out until (say) the data is distributed in a particular way, which renders your efforts meaningless. You'd actually have to study the generated plan to see if there's any possibility of it failing. Personally, I wouldn't even know how to pronounce a plan guaranteed safe, though I suppose it's possible in principle. Even so, I can't imagine that ever being easier than changing offending subexpressions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - that depends on the complexity of the plan, for simpler ones you could figure out ensuring the scalar was later, but you would also have to know specific data conditions couldn't ever occur for a given filter, I'd go fix the expression everytime, same as you.